# Rough computation of distance between 2 points

Tags: math, image-processing, geometry

I want to calculate the rough (approximate) distance between two points to reduce the computation overhead.

I am using the following formula for the distance between (x1, y1) & (x2, y2):

```
Dist = Mod (x1 - x2) + Mod (y1 - y2)
```

Where Mod is the Modulus operator such that Mod(x) = |X|.

This seems to be working.

I want to know, if I have missed out something ...

Comment: o__o ever heard of the Pythagorean Theorem?

Comment: @Mehrad, would love to use the euclidean distance, except for the square and the square root overhead.

Comment: Squaring numbers is pretty quick since it is just multiplying the number by itself; if you're lucky and you need to compare distances rather than calculate distances then you can skip the square root

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As long as you're getting the absolute value (like you stated |X|) and not using the modulus function then that will give you the manhattan distance between the two points

If that is what you want, then you've not missed anything

If you want the straight line distance use the pythagorean theorem. This is sqrt((x1 - x2) ^ 2 + (y1 - y2) ^ 2)

Answer (score 14):

Graphical representation of three usual distances:

[image]

(Note: this represents a circle of radius 4 in these three metrics.)

Comment: Isn't the red line 4*sqrt(2)? And isn't the line 8?

Comment: @mtrw The red line is `mod[x]+mod[y] == 4` and the blue line is `max[mod[x],mod[y]] == 4`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm totally missing something. Isn't the blue line `mod[x]+mod[y]`?

Comment: @mtrw Nope. The Blue is Chebyschev:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance . The Red one is Manhattan (or TaxiCab): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:TaxicabGeometryCircle.svg

Comment: But according to the first image on [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) the diagonal is Euclidean, the zig-zag is Manhattan.

Comment: @mtrw That image is confusing. That's the reason why I linked the other image. Look at the pictures in the last section (metrics) here http://www.comp.lancs.ac.uk/~kristof/research/notes/basicstats/index.html

Comment: The formula for Manhattan distance on that page is sum(abs(x_i-y_i)). In your picture, x = (4,0), y = (0,4), and sum(abs(4-0) + abs(0-4)) = 8. The picture shows a diagonal for Manhattan distance because it's saying that all point on that diagonal are the same distance from the origin. Hence a diagonal for Manhattan and a circle for Euclid.

Comment: Any distance starting at the origin that is 4 units in length (depending on distance metric you use) will finish at the different boundaries in the image. Its not evaluating the distance of the lines themselves. For manhattan, try any point along the red line such as (0,4) to the origin (0,0) and you'll get: sum(abs(0-0), abs(4-0)) == 4

Answer (score 3):

are you sure you have the Modulus operator correct? It looks like you are use MOD as ABSOLUTE

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

anyway, as Mehrdad says, using the pythagorean theorum:

```
Dist = Sqrt( (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 )
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to be specific in terms of distance that you want to calculate.

**Distance Formula:** Given the two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), the distance between these points is given by the formula:  [image]

This is the standard formula that we use in Co-Ordinate geometry to find the distance between points and is specialization of [MinKowski distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_distance) for One Dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Your distance metric is fine for *rough* distance. But (x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup> will give you the square of the actual distance. As long as you keep in mind that it's the square of the distance, this will be more accurate. And depending on the architecture you're implementing this on, it might be faster - the multiply might take less time than the branch in the modulus, or for hardware implementations might well take the same time. You will need to benchmark to be sure.

Comment: Note that `abs` typically doesn't require a branch -- it unconditionally sets one bit to zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to compare distances and save time, use not the distance itself, but its square: (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2. Don't take sqrt. So, your distances will work exactly as normal ones, but quickly. Counting dx=x1-x2 and dx2=dx*dx is even faster than taking ABS(you meant it, not MOD really), because  the last is a function and you have to pay for it.

ABS distance is a correct one - in theory. But what is the use of it, if it is rough for your targets?

Answer (score 0):

I made this algorithm to calculate the straight line distance between 2 points:

```js
var distance = function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
            //Distance Horizantally
            var horizontalDistance = 0;
            /Distance Vertically
            var verticalDistance = 0;
            
            if(x1 > x2) {
                horizantalDistance = x1 - x2;
            }
            else {
                horizantalDistance = x2 - x1;
            }
            
            if(y1 > y2) {
                verticalDistance = y1 - y2;
            }
            else {
                verticalDistance = y2 - y1;
            }

            var answer = 0;
            
            if(verticalDistance !== 0 && horizantalDistance !== 0) {
                //Use the Pathagoreum Theorum
                answer = Math.sqrt(verticalDistance + horizantalDistance);
            }
            else if(horizantalDistance === 0) {
                //Use the Vertical Distance
                answer = verticalDistance;
            }
            else if (verticalDistance === 0) {
                //Use the Horizantal distance
                answer = horizantalDistance;
            }
            //Return the answer
            return answer;
        }
```