# How do I get distance in python or c#?

Tags: python, c#

I want to be able to calculate the distance between two locations. So I have bill, his longitude and latitude is 5,6. And I have bob, his longitude and latitude is 9,2. Is there anything in c# or python that will make me able to get the distance in miles?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating the distance between 2 points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555355/calculating-the-distance-between-2-points)

Comment: @VijayNirmal - that might work on a flat earth.

Comment: @tdelaney Is that a requirement? How do you know it's not for the moon? Then He/She must say these are actual latitudes and longitude instead of providing a single digital number. user14624548 Can you confirm the requirement?

Comment: If these are Geo Points then check this post out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544286/calculate-distance-of-two-geo-points-in-km-c-sharp

Comment: @VijayNirmal - Something as exceptional as this being the moon instead of earth would need to be noted in the question. Latitude and longitude are not a euclidean grid on a sphere, a flat earth model. They are a euclidean grid on a mercator projection but then, miles between grid lines change as you move north sout.

Comment: You can do this in either language, but please pick one language for your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting distance between two points based on latitude/longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412462/getting-distance-between-two-points-based-on-latitude-longitude)

Answer (score 3):

### Distance between any 2 points on the surface shape (Earth) is calculated using the `Haversine formula`

1-First, convert the latitude and longitude values from decimal degrees to radians by dividing the values of longitude and latitude of both the points by 180/pi  `(pi=22/7)`

Value of Latitude in Radians = lat / (180/pi)
Value of Longitude in Radians = long / (180/pi)

2- after converting lat, long to Radians for the 2 points
you should have now
`(lat1_r,long1_r)` ,`(lat2_r,long2_r)`

3-Calculate distance now by
`d = 3963.0 * arccos[(sin(lat1_r) * sin(lat2_r)) + cos(lat1_r) * cos(lat2_r) * cos(long2_r– long1_r)]`

4- this distance will be in miles, to get it in km

`d in kilometers = 1.609344 * d in miles`

5- write the logic in any language you like

### Easy Haversine formula with code in Python

1-after converting lat,long to Radians for the 2 points
you should now have
`(lat1_r,long1_r)` ,`(lat2_r,long2_r)`

2- we need to get `a`,`c`, `d` using following formulas

[image]

`where  φ is latitude **(in radians)**, λ is longitude **(in radians)** , R is earth’s radius (mean radius = 6,371km);

#### Haversine formula Code in Python

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt ,atan2
def distance(lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2):
     
    # The math module contains a function named
    # radians which converts from degrees to radians.
    lon1 = radians(lon1)
    lon2 = radians(lon2)
    lat1 = radians(lat1)
    lat2 = radians(lat2)
      
    # Haversine formula
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
 
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
   # you can use atan2 instead of asin and get same result
   # c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a))

    # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
    r = 6371
      
    # calculate the result
    return(c * r)
```

#### if you believe the earth is flat then you can use `euclidean distance` :D

x is latitude  and y  is longitude
(x1,y1) the first point (x2,y2) is the second point, so you can build your own method in any language

`d=√((x2 – x1)² + (y2 – y1)²)`.

References

[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-distance-two-points-earth/#:~:text=For%20this%20divide%20the%20values,is%20the%20radius%20of%20Earth](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-distance-two-points-earth/#:%7E:text=For%20this%20divide%20the%20values,is%20the%20radius%20of%20Earth).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nsVsdHeTXIE&ab_channel=Qarbyte

Comment: assuming the surface is flat

Comment: @Nin17 yep,if he had 3D he would have to subtract each dim from it's its equivalent

Comment: @MohamedFathallah - but latitude / longitude are on a 3D sphere by definition.

Comment: @tdelaney so you think i should edit my answer to include the third dimensional

Comment: @MohamedFathallah - In this case, yes, because euclidean distance just isn't right for surface distance.

Comment: @tdelaney thanks so much for this information i will edit my answer now ^^